# How to subscribe to post request correctly in an Angular 8 app?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to submit post request and have difficulties to subscribe, the post request is not fire the rest api server.
Here is the service call:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

saveTrips(trips: TripObj[], id : string): Observable<any> {        
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Save/${id}`, JSON.stringify(trips), httpOptions);        
  }
```

And here is the component code when I'm trying to subscribe:

```
this.tripService.saveTrips(this.myTripsObjs, this.id)      
    .subscribe(
      (data) => {
          console.log(data);
      });
```

Here is the java rest api just in case you need to see it:

```
@POST
    @Path("Trips/Save/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")   
    public Response saveTrips(@PathParam("id") String id,
            List<Trip> tripsList) {        
       tripsDao.addTrips(tripsList);                        
       return Response.ok().entity("Trips saved successfully").build();
    }
```

I'm not getting any error in the console. Any idea how to make sure the request is fire the server api? 
(this code was working fine in Angular 5 app).
Thanks.

Comment: Hi You need to call second call back to get the error. `this.tripService.saveTrips(this.myTripsObjs, this.id)      
    .subscribe(
      (data) => {
          console.log(data);
      },(error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });`

Comment: Have you looked at the Network tab in your browser? Also you can add a second callback in the subscribe function which returns an error. `(error) => console.log(error);`

Comment: Seems correctly. There is no activity in the network-tab (webbrowser -> inspect)?

Comment: Then I suggest checking if the saveTrips method is being called to begin with. Without seeing the rest of the code there is no solution we can give

Comment: Shouldn't it be `id` i.e. `${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Save/${id}` and not `${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Save/${d}`

Comment: @ DTul  Which code you need to see? the rest api (java) ?

Comment: I added (error) but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: The network tab doen't show the request, I need to subscribe differently but I'm not sure how

Comment: If you can't see any activity on the network tab - you are not "invoking" a web request, your API is irrelevant. your code seems valid. go to your component directly, and do a simple request on init. `this.http.post(http://...path.to.api.../Trips/Save/someid, trips).subscribe(f => alert(JSON.stringify(f))); ` make sure you import `HttpClient` and inject it in your component constructor. does that work ?

Answer (score 0):

I had unsubscribe code, and it probably being executed before the request sent.
I fixed it by removing it.